# Irreducible abelian variety in an algebraic set.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Suppose $X$ is an algebraic set (not irreducible) over an algebraically closed field $k$, and $X$ is a commutative group variety. If $dim(X)>0$, can we find an irreducible abelian subvariety of positive dimension in $X$?

Comment: What if $X$ is affine?

Comment: @Mohan Umm, I cannot find an affine counterexample.

Comment: $G_m,G_a$ and disjoint union of these are affine commutative group schemes.